# Forming String Concatenation

Tags: string, algorithm

You are given a odd length string containing lowercase letters. It is also given that the string contains only one character **c** odd times and every other character even times.You have to say that is it possible to remove any one of c character and the string become concatenation of two equal string.
for example : aba as removing b the string becomes "aa" which is concatenation of "a"+"a"

Anyone can help how to approach this question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 3 options for the character to be removed.

- The character is in the middle. So just check if the first n/2 characters match the last n/2 characters.
- The character is in the second half. So the first n/2 characters are already good. Start checking the next characters. If you see one mismatch skip it (that's the character to be removed). If you see a second mismatch then this is not the solution.
- Last the character is in the first half. Similar to the previous option,  the last n/2 characters are good, so check the first n/2 +1 characters. Again if there's a mismatch skip it, but if there are two then this is not a solution.

So try all 3 options and see if any are able to find a solution. Complexity should be O(N) since you only need to go linearly through the string a few times.